# Is Rails still included by default in a clean installation of Mac OS X 10.7 (aka Lion)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, osx-lion

From reading this,

http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=lion-server-review

I see Apple has dropped MySQL in favour of Postgre, so I'm wondering if it includes Rails bindings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just upgraded my machine (which had Rails installed) to Lion, and tried this,

```
macbook:expenses Snips$ rails server
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

So, I guess the answer is no :-(

Comment: As a follow up to this...  I'm not sure if something has changed in the latest Lion updates, but I now find that if I perform a clean Lion installation, install my Rails App, and then perform 'bundle install' in the App directory, that is sufficient to get the App up and running.

Comment: I also went through this and found: I can install the code of an existing app and it works.  However trying to do a completely **new** app with `rails new abc` gives 'rails not installed' and so I will need to actuaally install rails to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the extra insight - please let us know how you go about installing Rails. Although I hadn't tried this (I'd just been working on existing apps, I did just try it and it works on my machine - I don't believe I've done a rails install).   btw, as an aside, my old Snow Leopard machine won't play nice installing Rails since the latest 10.6.8 security update :-/

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue. I'm not sure which is the default with Lion but I found that

```
/Library/Ruby/1.8/bin/rails
```

does the trick. Using sudo I moved the /usr/bin/rails to /usr/bin/rails.bak and symlinked to the other rails. That seems to work.

Interestingly, RubyMine found the correct rails command to use

Comment: Thanks, does that include bindings to Postgre?

Answer (score 1):

[BitNami Rubystack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) will work and provide you with a out-of-the-box Rails environment with MySQL on OS X (and a bunch of preconfigured, commonly used third-party libraries and apps). Disclaimer, I am one of the developers of RubyStack. It is distributed under the Apache 2.0 open source license

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation with the company each time you mention your product. Otherwise, it is considered as spam here.

Comment: I have done so in most other questions and is clearly specified in my profile as well. BitNami is not a company, and we do not make any money with the stacks (though it is sponsored by one and we provide support and services to some other open source companies such as Sugar, Alfresco, etc.). In any case, I have now updated my response. Also, I believe there was no need to downvote the answer as it is directly related to the topic.

Comment: I did not downvote. The spam flag works like that. It will go away after a while now that you updated your answer. Note however that you really should specify your affiliation in each of your answers, it is not enough to have it on your profile, so you should check that all your answers recommending your products include a disclaimer