# Installing Ruby on Rails - Mac OS Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion

I have downloaded Lion and looking to install Ruby on Rails I have been scanning the web for a way to do this but can't seem to find a easy way, could anyone point me in the correct direction.

Help Much Appreciated

Thanks

Comment: See this thread,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765098/is-rails-still-included-by-default-in-a-clean-installation-of-mac-os-x-10-7-aka

Comment: At this time (April 2014), Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9) is the current version, as is Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.1. This article [Install Ruby on Rails - Mac OS X Mavericks](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) provides up-to-date installation instructions.

Answer (score 47):

Below I try to resume my rails installation. It should work well.

**1) Download Xcode from Apple Application Store :**

use this link : [xcode](http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12)

**2) Install xcode :**

Use finder=>applications to locate "Xcode installation icon and double-click on it to begin the  installation

**2b.) For xcode 4.3. After installing xcode, launch it, navigate to Xcode->Preferences, Downloads tab. Install Command Line Tools. This will download and install C, compiler, loader and other command line utilities needed to compile & build the Ruby packages.

**3) use a terminal to install git:**

```
gem install git
```

and put this line in your .bash_profile (create one if none exists) :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/
```

**4) use a terminal to install rvm:**

```
bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

and run this command to update your .bash_profile :

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

**5) use a terminal to install ruby 1.9.2  and rails:**

```
rvm autolibs enable 
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm --default 1.9.2
gem update
gem install rails
```

Comment: I want to install Ruby 1.9.2, because there is a problem with OpenSSL in Ruby 1.9.3. I'm on OS X 10.7.3 and have Xcode 4.3.0. However Xcode 4.2+ is only supported by Ruby 1.9.3. http://www.christopherirish.com/2011/09/02/ruby-1-9-2-segmentation-fault-and-openssl/

Comment: by the way, just a trivial reminder, but don't forget to source your .bash_profile after adding those lines to your profile by doing '. ~/.bash_profile' ... and also, in step 3, for convenience sakes, you may have to do 'sudo gem install git' and also 'echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/" >> ~/.bash_profile' in the terminal

Answer (score 5):

As of the latest version of lion (and having installed sass/compass/haml), if you type "rails" in the terminal and you dont have it, it will tell you to just do a sudo install right there. Hope its as easy for you as it was for me.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I have follow this [link](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac) to install rails with `rvm` on Mac OS X Lion and I use [pow](http://pow.cx/) to run locally my application.