# installing rails stuck?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion

I am trying to installing rails on Lion but after the command

```
sudo gem install rails --version 3.0.1
```

It asks me for password, I entered password the cursor moves to next line and then nothing happens. Whats wrong?

```
Successfully installed rails-3.0.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.1...
File not found: lib
```

Comment: You say nothing happens then you quote some output - this is not consistent either nothing happens ot you get output

Comment: The command stuck for me tooo .. But this helped 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840719/installing-ruby-on-rails-mac-os-lion

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell what's wrong from your description to the problem. However, using system default gem command is not encouraged, you will want to use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/).

Comment: @coure2011 The downvote is most likely for inconsistency. `...and then nothing happens` is followed by the output, _clearly contradicting_ the previous statement.