# RVM won't install Rails to system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I've tried the following commands:

```
rvm system gem install rails
rvm system install rails
rvmsudo gem install rails
sudo gem install rails
```

After one of these commands, I get a message telling me to run `sudo gem install rails`. But it doesn't work.

I had no problems before to install rails on rvm 1.9.2 the Mac OSX 10.6.8 version.

**Could anyone help me with that?**

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed rvm successfully, test with `rvm info` so that it returns output then you just need to do `gem install rails` to install rails into the ruby version you are using with RVM - no sudo required. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: sudo is required if you've installed RVM system wide and not only for your user.

Answer (score 0):

First check either rvm install properly or not using this command

```
rvm --help
```

then install rails by this command

```
    gem install rails -v=3.2.1
```

Or any version you want..

Comment: thanks, but no soap.  --help works, but the install goes as the others

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have ruby 1.9.3 then use:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

or you may start from this:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3

$ rvm gemset create rails313

$ rvm use 1.9.3@rails313 --default

$ gem install rails -v 3.1.3
```

note: I use 1.9.3 as an example you can use other ruby version also.

Answer (score 0):

[Follow the documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#explained). Make sure you've got the necessary system requirements via `rvm requirements`. Unless you've got some bizarre user permissions in $HOME, there is no reason to use sudo w/ rvm on your system.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have installed `build_essentials`, also try `rvm requirements`, which gives all dependencies, install all using `rvmsudo` command
See also: [Installing Ruby on Rails - Mac OS Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840719/installing-ruby-on-rails-mac-os-lion)

Answer (score 0):

First check whether all dependencies are satisfied by running:

```
$ rvm requirements
```

**next:**

```
$ rvm install ruby
```

**next:**

```
$ gem install rails
```

**Note:** You may have to use `sudo` or `rvmsudo` before the commands depending on whether its system-wide install or user specific.