# Installing Ruby on Mac OS X 10.8.2

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, makefile

I have referred to [Installing Ruby on Rails - Mac OS Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840719/installing-ruby-on-rails-mac-os-lion) and followed [Alain Beauvois's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840719/installing-ruby-on-rails-mac-os-lion/8464619#8464619) and got pretty much everything up. The only difference is I am using 1.9.3 instead of 1.9.2.

I have created `.bash_profile` and even made sure that is there by `open -e .bash_profile` and even added the line as stated by Alain Beauvois.

But what seems to be the problem now is I am getting this error:

```
Error running 'make', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The referenced log contains this:

```
[2013-02-02 21:41:52] make
    CC = clang
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = clang -dynamic -bundle
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/rvm/usr/include -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin12.2.1 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  
    SOLIBS = 
compiling regparse.c
regparse.c:582:15: error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'st_index_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    return t->num_entries;
    ~~~~~~ ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [regparse.o] Error 1
```

I even tried

```
rvm -install ruby-1.9.3-p374
```

but still get the same error. I did get some weird errors before I got to this part but after I reran it with an addition of `sudo` in front of it, it worked. AFAIK, `sudo` = doing something with `su` permissions/privileges, right?

Comment: Did you read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/make.log?

Comment: Just download this kit from http://railsinstaller.org/#osx. It includes everything you need to get started with ruby/rails development

Comment: Too long to post here, so pastebin it is: http://pastebin.com/R5VY6HPw Just wondering, did any of my actions earlier caused any impacts to my Mac? Maybe change settings etc

Comment: @AshishSaihgal will try that solution. Would like to do everything fresh and just use the installer. Anything I can do to undo the changes I made? Thanks!

Comment: How about `rvm install 1.9.3`? just type version number.

Comment: That looks more like a Ruby bug. I think you should report it.

Comment: @Linuxios gosh, for a newbie, that really killed my spirit to try things out. Anyone have maybe a better way? (If there is any..)

Comment: @DuaneAdam: Yes. Don't try to install the absolute latest patch version. Try to install 1.9.3-p362.

Comment: @at2c that was the first thing I did. In the op, I said I even tried with "-p374"

Comment: By the way, this is one of the best written and best understood first questions I've ever seen.

Comment: I wrote an article about this, just 2 weeks ago:  http://simonewebdesign.it/blog/how-to-setup-osx-for-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: @Linuxios thank you, I am trying my best not to 'spam' and make my question easy to understand for the community and for me so that I can get my answers fast and correctly. By the way, still the same error.

Comment: @DuaneAdam: Hm. Try installing 192-p290 if you're ok with having 1.9.2 instead of 1.9.3.

Comment: @Linuxios some screenshots: i) http://i.imgur.com/vqLYpVu.png ii) http://i.imgur.com/mPkuhwj.png

Comment: Now I am getting `The provided compiler '/usr/bin/gcc' is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.`

Comment: @DuaneAdam: Wait one second.

Comment: @DuaneAdam just go and delete /usr/local/rvm directory if you installed it as root else delete $HOME/.rvm directory and then just use the installer I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just found [this](https://gist.github.com/3237860). I think this is what you need to do.

First, if you haven't already, download [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and install it. Then run the following two commands:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install apple-gcc42
```

Too get real UNIX GCC. Then, to install 1.9.3 run:

```
CC=/opt/local/bin/gcc-apple-4.2 rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194 --enable-shared --without-tk --without-tcl
```

Which tells rvm to install Ruby using UNIX GCC without Tk or Tcl which require X11 (left out of OSX 10.8). If you want things like readline support, OpenSSL, etc., check out the above linked gist.

Comment: Now 'stuck' at `attempting to fetch livm-3/1-3.1_6.darwin` My guess is it is downloading a big sized file.

Comment: Looks like it will take quite a long time to download and I need to go to bed for now. Will get back to you first thing in the morning. I'll let it download through the night.

Comment: Everything is done, took awhile to download. How do I know it is installed correctly or configured correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Genius. It works! Whatever would we do without Stack Overflow? I was struggling with ruby and homebrew updates on El Capitan and this was the final piece in the puzzle.

Comment: @Tokn: glad the answer was so helpful!

Answer (score 31):

I had the exact same error, but am using brew instead of MacPorts. All I had to do was:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
rvm get stable
rvm install 1.9.3-p374
```

I didn't have to set the CC environment variable as some instructions point out. HTH!

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help - I didn't realize MacPorts and brew did the same general thing, and couldn't figure out why the "port" command wasn't working.  Still not sure why port didn't work, but I'm glad it didn't, since my work uses homebrew.

Comment: Note to myself, It looks like i might not have accepted the xcode command line tools so I had to run `xcodebuild -license`, then read the 'rvm requirements' and found I had to `brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42 libtool pkg-config openssl readline libyaml sqlite libxml2 libxslt libksba`

Answer (score 20):

If you are using rbenv and ruby-build instead of rvm, you have to do this:

```
env CC=gcc rbenv install 1.9.3-p392
```

If this doesn't work, try this:

```
# this export must be done before every new ruby build
export CC=gcc
# use the version you wish to install
rbenv install 1.9.3-p392
```

If it doesn't work, you need to install gcc first:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/dupes
# install apple-gcc, only once needed
brew install apple-gcc42
```

Until the ruby folks build a clang compatible ruby version, you have to export the CC variable before every build of a new ruby version

Comment: You actually only need to run `export CC=gcc` before `rbenv install 1.9.3-p385`.

Comment: Yep only need to runt export, gcc is included in xcode i think.

Comment: This was all it took for me. I'm using fish shell so my command looked like `env CC=gcc rbenv install 1.9.3-p392`

Answer (score 3):

This also worked in rbenv on OSX 10.8.2 + XCode 4.6

```
$ export CC=gcc
$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p385 -v
```

But is also useful to know that homebrew can install another version of gcc if apple changes the command line tools of Xcode in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I just did (after installing XCode command line tools):

```
$ export CC=gcc
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

And although it said "Ruby 'ruby-1.9.3-p374' was built using clang - but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors." - it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me as well on ruby-1.9.3-p385 with no homebrew or Macports installed.

```
export CC=gcc
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Gave message "Ruby 'ruby-1.9.3-p385' was built using clang - but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors." after completing task.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another answer to the list... I'm using ruby-install, and this is what worked for me:

```
CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 ruby-install ruby 1.9.3-p0
```

Comment: This worked for me after performing the `brew` tasks outlined in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14761862/567863).

Answer (score 0):

I tried `apple-gcc42` and `CC=/usr/bin/gcc` without any luck so I'm not sure if they are necessary. I'm using the `rbenv` manager and so this is what worked for me when trying to install `1.9.3-p385`

```
brew install readline
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=$(brew --prefix readline)" rbenv install 1.9.3-p385
```

Found it on [this blog](http://rors.org/2011/10/25/compiling-ruby-on-a-fresh-lion-install)

Answer (score 0):

For the record: Works for me with `rbenv`, `ruby 1.9.3-p385`, **`gcc48`** (`brew install gcc48`) on `Darwin Kernel Version 15.2.0`. (there were lots of warnings during compilation that I ignored, ruby works fine so far).

I just had to set `CC=gcc-4.8` before `rbenv install 1.9.3-p385`