# Ruby on Rails error, Ruby was not installed but it is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662569/installing-ruby-on-mac-os-x-10-8-2) and followed Linuxios' answer, everything was working fine but then I get

```
-bash: export: `[[': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-s': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/duaneadam/.rvm/scripts/rvm': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `]]': not a valid identifier
```

So, I went and removed from .bash__profile via Terminal.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/ [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

.. thinking that lines of code is the problem but what I get after that is even worse. For some reasons.. Ruby is not installed.. again. 
So, I re-added the lines of code and tried rebooting/restarting my Mac but problem still persist.
Screenshots:

.bash_profile:
[image: .bash_profile]
Solution please? I even tried re-installing using his method.
Gosh, this is hard maybe Ruby on Rails isn't just for me.

Comment: Make sure to install the command line tools either from within xcode or as a standalone installation.

Comment: Do check out this [awesome tutorial by Moncef Belyamani](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/) covering step-by-step instructions for setting up Git, RVM, & Ruby on Mac. Made it a breeze when I tried to set up my dev env on a new mac recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up ruby with rvm can get pretty complicated at times.
A few golden rules is never to sudo when using a package manager like rvm.

Try the following:

- `rvm implode` (This essentially removes the rvm installation
  completely.)
- Remove all references of rvm from ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc
- `which ruby` (The output should be something like /usr/bin, also `ruby --version` should be 1.8.7, the default bundled with OS X.)
- Install rvm again in a single user mode.
- Install the ruby version of your choice.
- Make sure to create the .rvmrc file where ever the ruby program resides. (Typical contents of .rvmrc -> `rvm use ruby-version@gemset-name --create`; eg: `rvm use 1.9.3@my-awesome-project --create`)
- cd into the directory with .rvmrc
- Make sure the right gemset is loaded with `rvm gemset list`

Also ensure that rvm is loaded as a function. (You can verify this by typing `type rvm | head -1` in the console.)

Some more points, which were helpful to me from http://jfire.io/blog/2012/03/02/xcode-4-dot-3-homebrew-and-ruby/:

- Install apple-gcc42, autoconf and automake (Using a package manager like homebrew can be useful.)
- Also `rvm requirements` tells you what are the other tools you need to install.

Cheers!

Comment: Done with rvm implode but it says some files need to be removed manually. Removed .bash_profile and .bashrc the which ruby outputs the same as you posted. That is `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` I would suggest installing vanilla rvm and getting it working.

Comment: You know what.. I give up, I think I'll remove Ruby and Rails. I have tried a lot of method. Googling this and that, watching videos, reading wikis. How do I remove everything?

Comment: Just in case anyone wondering how to remove: Here are some links, i) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-to-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system ii) http://mkoby.com/2011/06/03/completely-removing-rvm/

Comment: All right.. But if you would state the issues you are getting, then perhaps I would be of better help.

Comment: Okay, let's say after I removed everything. From where do I start? You said to reinstall RVM but which method? There are way too much and I am quite confused.

Comment: The script `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` should help you setup rvm.

Comment: `rvm requirements` first. Make sure rvm is setup properly. Try `type rvm | head -1` to ensure rvm is a function.

Comment: `brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42 libtool pkg-config openssl readline libyaml sqlite libxml2 libxslt libksba` should help you.

Comment: Okay, after that? I'm done (I guess) other than the errors and warnings. I think the errors should be fine as it says that it is already installed but as for the MacPorts, I'm unsure.

Comment: I guess that is it then.. `brew doctor` if you have any issues with brew itself.
But I guess most of the issues are ironed out. Try installing a ruby version.