# Cython installation warning on Mac OS X 10.9.4

Tags: python, macos, installation, osx-mavericks, cython

I am trying to install the Cython package for Python 2.7.5. I am getting this output when running setup.py from the source code: (After it hits this warning it freezes)

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing Cython.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Cython.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Cython.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to Cython.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'Cython.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'
writing manifest file 'Cython.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe 
-fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG 
-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall 
-Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 
-pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 
-c Cython/Plex/Scanners.c 
-o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/Cython/Plex/Scanners.o
Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:3105:31: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'
  [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
__pyx_v_self->input_state = __pyx_v_input_state;
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

The same thing happens when I use pip to install. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: This might be related: [Installing Ruby on Mac OS X 10.8.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662569/installing-ruby-on-mac-os-x-10-8-2). In short: You need a real GCC, Apple's LLVM Clang won't do.

Comment: Works fine for me on OSX 10.9.4 with both included python 2.7.5 (which ran `cc`) and homebrew python 2.7.8 (which ran `clang`). Maybe try with a fresh python?

Comment: fresh python worked, thanks!