# Target Integrity - The file "Pods-ios.xcconfig" couldn't be opened because its path couldn't be resolved. It may be missing"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm trying to utilize the four Examples that ship with RestKit Version 0.20.1  Currently trying to Build RKSearchExample.  The Build "succeeds" but no simulator appears and I get two warnings

1st one - Target Intergrity - The file "Pods-ios.xcconfig" couldn't be opened because there is no such file. ....

2nd one - Target Integrity - The file "Pods-ios.xcconfig" couldn't be opened because its path couldn't be resolved. It may be missing"

I assume that this file is missing and even though the Build succeeds with only warnings, it missing is causing the project to not actually complete its Build.

Does anyone have any idea where to find this file?  Has one built the Examples included in RestKit successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: Run `git submodule update -i --recursive`.  I'll bet RestKit is using the xcconfigs repo as a dependancy, and that you haven't finished pulling it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I downloaded RestKit as a .zip file and don't appear to have a .git repository on my Mac. Any other thoughts on what I should try?  Also, I can't seem to find any info on the xxconfigs repo, can you point me toward that?

Comment: `git clone` it down from github, then.

Comment: I able to get the warnings to go away by 1.) Installing Ruby and Ruby Gems via this StackOverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840719/installing-ruby-on-rails-mac-os-lion, 2.) Installing CocoaPods and building according their instructions, 3.) Re-installing RestKit as a git clone and using the instructions RestKit install with CocoaPods instructions. Thanks!  The RestKit Example Project build successfully, but don't seem to do anything yet.  That is another question to research tomorrow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Came across same problem. Solved it by

1. Make sure .pch file is updated and missing frameworks are added to Build Phases (See 'Adding Frameworks to the Precompiled Header File' in  https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-via-CocoaPods)
2. Close the workspace, re-run '$ pod install' in the project directory,
3. Re-open the project (using .xcworkspace), do a Clean and Build.

Answer (score -3):

Hey i had this same problem, I was getting the following error when running pod update however i didn’t realise the update wasn’t working.

$ pod update

Analyzing dependencies
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb:422:in `open': No such file or directory

It was because I forgot to run "pod setup" after installing cocoapods.
I ran pod setup from the terminal, followed it up with pod update (or pod install) and everything went to plan.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Don't do this pod setup!  I didn't look at vote count closely enough, and it pulled a 600mb cocoapods repo for me.  Now "pod install" always wants to pull the cocoapods repo, if it doesn't exist.  Plus didn't fix issue